# Should I tell my supervisor if one of my direct reports is pursuing another job?

Tags: work-environment

I supervise 5 people and one them confided to me she is pursuing another job possibly. She was very emotional and cried a lot. She has not made a final decision yet. Am I obligated to tell my immediate supervisor?

Comment: a) Do you have something like a mandatory notice period in your country? If yes: b) Who should be noticed, you or your supervisor? c) Is this employee planning on just quitting without notice? ... If the answer to (b) is "you" or the answer to (c) is "no" or "I don't know", you have no reason to report anything (except maybe the reason she cried, if it is because of something bad at the workplace, like bullying)

Comment: Don't spread rumors. If you tell management and she decides _not_ to change jobs, you may needlessly damage her relationship with the company. If it isn't your job, stay out of it.

Comment: You are not obligated to tell your supervisor until she actually resigns. You are her supervisor, it is your job (usually) to deal with resignations.

Comment: Important distinction: do you **supervise** or do you **manage**? To clarify: are you in charge of building (and replacing) your team or do you only have a reporting role to the actual manager?

Comment: This is a nobrainer .She confided which means told you in confidence.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: Absolutely no. Long answer:

We always advice people: Don't tell anyone that you want to leave. When you signed for the new job, hand in your notice. Don't tell anyone any earlier. Your post demonstrates one of the reasons why.

The lady in question made a mistake. The best thing you can do for everyone involved is to act as if she never had made that mistake, and perhaps spend some thought on what you would do if she left. There are four other people, each of which could hand in their notice right this morning. You should be prepared for that kind of situation. Be glad that you got some warning. Don't spoil it.

Consider that for all you know she may still be working at your place twenty years from now. Now if you go to your manager and tell him or her, and it gets back to that employee who suddenly has no intention of leaving, one possibility is that to avoid any damage to her career, she will deny very loudly that she ever thought about resignation and damage your reputation badly. And that's what a reasonable person would do, because clearly you showed that you would deserve nothing else. You were willing to throw her under the boss; there's no reason why she wouldn't do the same with you.

Even if that doesn't happen, you would have destroyed your relationship with that employee. And for what? What good does it do to anyone if you tell your management? And if she *does* leave, chances are good that word gets out what you did, which damages your relationship with all the other employees, and there may be more resignations, but this time without any warning.

Comment: -1. If OP is part of the management structure it should be understood that he can't be told things in confidence: managers sometimes need to act on what people tell them. The OP has an opportunity here to handle this information gracefully. That means an open  conversation with the person looking to leave about their concerns, not pushing them out prematurely and respecting the decision to move on. That is a great way to establish a solid reputation and to make it easier for other people to give loads of notice early.

Answer (score 1):

Generally not a good idea to pass on information you're unsure about, it's just hearsay, particularly if it was given to you in confidence.

Until she makes up her mind for sure (which means handing in an actual resignation), then there is no need to report anything and even then unless she's giving it to you, it's not your responsibility. In the same way that you're under no obligation to repeat every piece of gossip that you hear. If there is a clear reason for doing so then that is another matter, such as wanting her to be talked out of it and helped in some way. But be very careful of getting involved in other people's dramas, best practice in my opinion is not to get involved at all.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, why is this person considering resigning? Is it the work environment? Is it the work? Is there something you can do to handle this and convince her to stay.

Secondly, 
Don't tell, but start to make plans for how to handle this departure. Has this person some unique knowledge or responsibility? Then start to schedule work rotatations. Perhaps start to get active on job sites and see if there are replacements available. If a recruitment requires your bosses approval and could take time, then start to prepare for it now.

With this information, you have the possibility to have a complete plan ready if/when the resignation happens. Take advantage of this.